# How do I concatenate tables with different properties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two tables with different columns.

**Balance.cs**

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    public string Asset { get; set; }
    public decimal ValueInUSD { get; set; }
```

**Reserve.cs**

```
    public decimal? Balance { get; set; }
    public string Asset { get; set; }
```

**MainTable.cs**

```
    public string Asset { get; set; }
    public decimal BalanceFromBalanceTable{ get; set; }
    public decimal BalanceFromReserveTable{ get; set; }
```

My goal is to fill **MainTable** with data from **Balance** and **Reserve** tables. Problem is that these tables have different properties.

EDIT: 
Example with data as requested.

```
**Balance table**
Asset - USD; Balance - 25; 
Asset - BTC; Balance - 10;
**rest of the columns are irrelevant

**Reserve table**
Asset - USD; Balance -200;
Asset - BTC; Balance - 1;

**Main Table**
Asset - USD; BalanceFromBalanceTable - 25; BalanceFromReserveTable - 200;
Asset - BTC; BalanceFromBalanceTable - 10; BalanceFromReserveTable - 1;
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add some example data for `Balance` and `Reserve` and show us how you would want that to be converted to `MainTable`.

Comment: Could you add an example with the problematic queries?

Comment: seems that you have relational tables that should not be **concatenated**. Are you asking about [**joining**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause) ? To get MainTable joined with the Balance and Reverse for example ?

Comment: Read the needed objects from your Balance an Reserve table and for each object there create a new MainTable object and save it. BulkInsert's could help here.

Comment: Do you expect your data be joined based on Asset ?

Comment: @AbdullahDibas yes. Edited post. Added example

Comment: You just need to iterate through all items in Balance, for each item look for a match in Reserve, and with that two items, create a new item in MainTable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var mainTableCol = from b in balance
join r in reserve on b.Asset equals r.Asset
select new MainTable(){ Asset = b.Asset
                       ,BalanceFromBalanceTable = b.balance
                       ,BalanceFromReserverTable = r.balance };
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it like this :

```
    List<Balance> actives = item.GetItems();
    List<Reserve> liabilities = Reserve.GetLiabilities();
    List<MainTable> main= new List<MainTable>();
                foreach(var active in actives)
                {
                    foreach(var liability in liabilities)
                    {
                        if (active.AssetId == liability.AssetId)
                        {
                            main.Add(new MainTable
                            {
                                Active = active.Balance,
                                Liability = liability.Deposits,
                                AssetId = active.AssetId
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
```